# Capistrano/Puma : Unable to load application: ArgumentError: missing keyword: :root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Rails 6, Mysql, Ubuntu 20.04
I would like deploy with Capistrano Puma.

I have this error in my website :

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

Error into my log : puma.error.log :

```
/home/ubuntu/apps/appex/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activestorage-
6.1.4.1/lib/active_storage/service/disk_service.rb:14:in `initialize': missing keyword: :root (ArgumentError)

  from /home/ubuntu/apps/appex/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activestorage-6.1.4.1/lib/active_storage/service.rb:61:in `new'
```

Log Nginx :
`2021/11/16 10:05:02 [crit] 3361147#3361147: *6 connect() to unix:///home/ubuntu/apps/appex/shared/tmp/sockets/appex-puma.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client`

Comment: The relevant information,`storage.yml`, is missing from the ticket. That's where the error is coming from. You can clear most of the ticket's content.

Comment: storage.yml 
`test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk`

Comment: What do you have in production.rb for `config.active_storage.service` ?

Comment: Please read, https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#setup

Comment: i removed before this line, I don't know why..: root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
I added now and it's work thanks you very much !

Comment: Should I add an answer?

Comment: yes, and I put resolved after
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error comes from a misconfigured `storage.yml` in your environment. You are missing the `root` key.

For more information on how to set up ActiveStorage, read [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#setup).